# persistLowerCase not in scope from Persistent Haskell package example

Tags: haskell, persistent

I'm trying to follow the documentation here https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent and am seeing that this part:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
|]
```

is issuing an error `Not in scope: ‘persistLowerCase’` and I was wondering how I can resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you `import Database.Persist.TH`?

Comment: In the latest version of `persist-template`, it still has a `persistUpperCase` constant as `QuasiQuoter`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried, but when I do I get `Could not find module ‘Database.Persist.TH’` without any advice on what packages to add to resolve this

Comment: you need to install the `persist-template` package.

Comment: thanks! installing `persistent-template` resolved it!

Answer (score 1):

As @Willem Van Onsem pointed out, you need to ensure `persist-template` is installed, and then `import Database.Persist.TH` to bring `persistLowerCase` into scope.